# How to set multiple file patterns in R when copying files from one folder to another?

Tags: r

At work I have files that are added to a folder path as they are received and accepted. They are .wdf files that I need to convert from wdf to csv. I then want to connect the files into a single file that can be filtered by a column name. So I'm trying to pull a subset of the files from numerous folders based on extension and date, copy those that I want into another folder, and then I will connect those.

File names that I want to pull are in the form of:

```
"//xyz/ExternalUsers/em/em18thjudic/uploaded_files/ACCEPTED_201907101310_UIXD#FGE18thJULDWC2Q2019.wdf"
```

I want all files in that path that end in .wdf and fall between a certain date (currently the month of July). I would also prefer to be able to have it pull only new files when I run the script but I haven't figured that out yet. I can get it to pull files with either the date or the file type but not both.

I have tried using tapply with file.mtime to pull by date. This didn't work so I tried to pull by files that contain certain upload dates in name.

```
files <- list.files(
  path="//sptw02/ExternalUsers/em", 
  pattern = "\\.wdf$|._201907.", 
  full.names = TRUE, 
  recursive = TRUE)

dirs <- dirname(files)
lastfiles <- tapply(files, dirs, function(v) v[which.max(file.mtime(v))])
```

what I've tried:

1) `pattern = "\\.wdf$|._201907.",`

2) `pattern = c("(\\.wdf$,._201907.)"),`

3) `pattern = "\\.wdf"|"._201707.",`

I can only get it to pull either files containing that date in the name or the .wdf file extension

I expect to grab only the files that contain patterns I'm filtering for and to be copied into another folder. Instead it is copying only all files that have .wdf or _201907. I can not get both pulled. It is pulling in everything when it copies.

Comment: `pattern = "_201907.*\\.wdf$"`

Comment: This worked perfectly - thank you very much!